# Point ivy dependency at a local file?

Tags: java, ivy

I've got a main project where module A depends on a a .jar file created by the build for module B. While I'm in development, I'm modifying B regularly, then building B to create the library, then building A to use these changes.

Is there a way to point module A's ivy file to the jar file my module B build creates? Given I'm iterating multiple times, I don't want to check module B's jar into ivy over and over. It's also annoying to have to copy the jar into module A's build directory structure after every module B build.

Actually, for me it's worse, as I have about 4 modules in something of a dependency tree (A->B->CD). If it were just A and B I'd probably just live with it, but I'm getting sick of copying jar files around after the submodule builds and thought if there was a way to override the ivy file dependency line to look locally then that'd make life a lot simpler.

Comment: Are you working in an IDE or from the command line?  Do you need the dependency there in both cases or only in one for debugging?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pointing the Ivy dependency at your locally built module isn't the way to solve this. Instead when you build module B publish it to your local Ivy repository. When you resolve your dependencies for module A it will pull down module B from your local repository.

[From the Ivy docs on the local repository](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.2.0/tutorial/defaultconf.html):

> The local repository is particularly
>   useful when you want to do something
>   without being disturbed by anything
>   else happening in the environment.
>   This means that whenever ivy is able
>   to locate a module in this repository
>   it will be used, no matter of what is
>   available in others.
>
> For instance, if you have a module
>   declaring a dependency on the module
>   foo in revision latest.integration,
>   then if a revision of foo is found in
>   the local repository, it will be used,
>   even if a more recent revision is
>   available in other repositories.
>
> This may be disturbing for some of
>   you, but imagine you have to implement
>   a new feature on a project, and in
>   order to achieve that you need to
>   modify two modules: you add a new
>   method in module foo and exploit this
>   new method in module bar. Then if you
>   publish the module foo to your local
>   repository, you will be sure to get it
>   in your bar module, even if someone
>   else publish a new revision of foo in
>   the shared repository (this revision
>   not having the new method you are
>   currently adding).
>
> But be careful, when you have finished
>   your development and publish it on the
>   shared you will have to clean your
>   local repository to benefit from new
>   versions published in the shared
>   repository.
>
> Note also that modules found in the
>   local repository must be complete,
>   i.e. they must provide both a module
>   descriptor and the published
>   artifacts.

The [Using Ivy in multiple projects environment](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.2.0/tutorial/multiproject.html) documentation has an example `publish-local` Ant task that you might find useful.